# Como crear el archivo de produccion en react con npm run build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build

Estoy tratando de crear el archivo de produccion en react con npm run build  pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
throw new RemovedPluginError(errorMessage);
                        ^
Error: webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.minimize instead.
```

El npm start funciona correctamente. Yo puedo ver la aplicación en mi localhost pero problema parece ser el npm run build.

Busque en internet y la mayoria recomienda instalar TerserPlugin, lo hice y copie el siguiente codigo en el archivo webpackDevServer.config.js

const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({ /* additional options here */ })],
  },
}
```

Pero sigue saliendo el mismo error al correr npm run build, Alguna idea de cual puede ser el problema?

Fragmento package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "animate-sass": "^0.8.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.8",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "preload-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "terser-brunch": "^4.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.5",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./src node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./src node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./src node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
```

Comment: a mi me funciono cuando tuve ese problema: https://github.com/keithweaver/MERN-boilerplate/issues/13#issuecomment-510825808

Comment: @Isaac, sabes en que archivo va esa parte de codigo?

Comment: en tu archivo webpack, creo que nombreaste a ese archivo `webpackDevServer.config.js`

Comment: @Isaac, lo hice pero no funciono :(